# How to avoid using same function multiple times in Query and speed up the data retrieval

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IR.SRG(
    IR_item IN VARCHAR2,
    IR_comp     VARCHAR2,
    IR_locn     VARCHAR2,
    IR_Type     VARCHAR2,
    IR_fromdate DATE,
    IR_tilldate DATE,
  )
 RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  IR_qty NUMBER;
  myLocations sys.odcivarchar2list; --collection

BEGIN
     IF IR_locn = 'ALL' THEN
       myLocations := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('D2','D4','D5','D11');
    ELSE
       myLocations := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('D2');
    END IF;

 IF IR_TYPE       = 'O' then
    SELECT SUM(QTY)
    INTO IR_qty
    FROM STOCK_LEDGER
    WHERE ITEM_CODE    = IR_item
    AND LOCATION_CODE IN
    (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(myLocations)
  )
  AND DOCUMENTDATE <= IR_TILLDATE
  AND DOCUMENTDATE >= IR_FROMDATE;
END IF;

 IF IR_TYPE       = 'C' then
    SELECT SUM(QTY)
    INTO IR_qty
    FROM STOCK_LEDGER
    WHERE ITEM_CODE    = IR_item
    AND LOCATION_CODE IN
    (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(myLocations)
  )
  AND DOCUMENTDATE <= IR_TILLDATE
  AND DOCUMENTDATE >= IR_FROMDATE
  AND Some other conditions;;
END IF;

--Some Other Conditions

RETURN (NVL (IR_QTY, 0));
EXCEPTION
  WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
   RETURN 0;
END;
```

This function is called from a query multiple times. For example:

```
SELECT   ITEM_CODE,
         ITEM_NAME,
         IR.SRG (IM.ITEM_CODE,
                 'Company1',
                 'ALL',
                 'O',
                 '01/01/2009',
                 '12/31/2010'),
         IR.SRG (IM.ITEM_CODE,
                 'Company1',
                 'ALL',
                 'C',
                 '01/01/2009',
                 '12/31/2010')
, -- Function Called with other Conditions                 
  FROM   ITEM_MASTER IM
```

Example, I have around 1500 items, so for each item in the above query, the function is called 2 times, one for `'O'` `IR_Type` and another for `'C'` `IR_Type`. So the function is called a 3000 times. I have 8 different types of `IR_Type` and around 15000 items. It is called 120000 times which slows the data retrieval for about 2 hours, which is very troublesome.

I need help in retrieving the data by any other proper way which can speed up the report.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See how far you get without using the function.

```
select item_code
      ,item_name
      ,(select sum(qty)
          from stock_ledger
         where item_code = im.item_code,
           and location_code in ('D2', 'D4', 'D5', 'D11')
           and documentdate <= to_date(:TO_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
           and documentdate >= to_date(:FROM_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) as something1
      ,ir.srg(im.item_code, 'Company1', 'ALL', 'C', '01/01/2009', '12/31/2010')
      , -- Function Called with other Conditions                 
  from item_master im
```

Comment: The parameters are dynamic which are passed by user running the report. I cannot hardcode it.

Comment: How does that make a difference?. I'm just following your example.  Use bind variables.

Comment: there should be some other way, like making multiple functions or using a procedure or package, i'm just guessing.

Comment: Renes recommendation should do the job. If you really want to use a function then you have to rewrite the function completely. This function should be called once and result your table data and your calculated columns. Declare it as a `pipelined` function. Parameter should be a `ref cursor` (i.e. input is selection of your item_master). Inside this function loop over the cursor and determine further data according to your existing logic. There exist a lot of examples in the web. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Because of different parameter values you should call it twice but you could use result cache for better performance.
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6978972926020

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IR.SRG(
IR_item IN VARCHAR2,
IR_comp     VARCHAR2,
IR_locn     VARCHAR2,
IR_Type     VARCHAR2,
IR_fromdate DATE,
IR_tilldate DATE,
  )
 RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC RESULT_CACHE IS
    BEGIN

       IF IR_locn = 'ALL' THEN
       myLocations := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('D2','D4','D5','D11');
    ELSE
       myLocations := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('D2');
    END IF;

 IF IR_TYPE       = 'O' then
    SELECT SUM(QTY)
    INTO IR_qty
    FROM STOCK_LEDGER
    WHERE ITEM_CODE    = IR_item
    AND LOCATION_CODE IN
    (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(myLocations)
  )
  AND DOCUMENTDATE <= IR_TILLDATE
  AND DOCUMENTDATE >= IR_FROMDATE;
END IF;

 IF IR_TYPE       = 'C' then
    SELECT SUM(QTY)
    INTO IR_qty
    FROM STOCK_LEDGER
    WHERE ITEM_CODE    = IR_item
    AND LOCATION_CODE IN
    (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(myLocations)
  )
  AND DOCUMENTDATE <= IR_TILLDATE
  AND DOCUMENTDATE >= IR_FROMDATE
  AND Some other conditions;;
END IF;

--Some Other Conditions

RETURN (NVL (IR_QTY, 0));
EXCEPTION
  WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
   RETURN 0;
END;
```

Comment: The performance increased significantly !!! Let me verify the data and get back to you.